# pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")

Tags: mysql, heroku, mysql-workbench, discord.py, mysql-python

I'm currently building a bot using a mysql database and I'm trying to run it on heroku. However, the database refuses to connect to the database due to my hostname being localhost. How do I make the mysql database connect to heroku?

**Extra Info if you want more information:**

I've done a bit of research and I've found out that I need to change my mysql database hostname to 0.0.0.0 to get it to connect to anywhere. But I don't know what the port for that should be. Can someone help me out? How do I connect my heroku discord bot to the database and allow it to function? This is the full heroku log error.

```
2020-08-18T13:45:40.371647+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-08-18T13:45:43.831500+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-08-18T13:45:43.831536+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/sit
e-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 571, in connect
2020-08-18T13:45:43.831919+00:00 app[worker.1]: **kwargs)
2020-08-18T13:45:43.831924+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/soc
ket.py", line 724, in create_connection
2020-08-18T13:45:43.832413+00:00 app[worker.1]: raise err
2020-08-18T13:45:43.832418+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/soc
ket.py", line 713, in create_connection
2020-08-18T13:45:43.832917+00:00 app[worker.1]: sock.connect(sa)
2020-08-18T13:45:43.832945+00:00 app[worker.1]: ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connect
ion refused
2020-08-18T13:45:43.832949+00:00 app[worker.1]:
2020-08-18T13:45:43.832950+00:00 app[worker.1]: During handling of the above exception, ano
ther exception occurred:
2020-08-18T13:45:43.832950+00:00 app[worker.1]:
2020-08-18T13:45:43.832953+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-08-18T13:45:43.832980+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "sky_rpg.py.py", line 15, in <module>
2020-08-18T13:45:43.833120+00:00 app[worker.1]: cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
2020-08-18T13:45:43.833124+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/sit
e-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 94, in Connect
2020-08-18T13:45:43.833306+00:00 app[worker.1]: return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
2020-08-18T13:45:43.833310+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/sit
e-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 327, in __init__
2020-08-18T13:45:43.833580+00:00 app[worker.1]: self.connect()
2020-08-18T13:45:43.833585+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/sit
e-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 619, in connect
2020-08-18T13:45:43.833985+00:00 app[worker.1]: raise exc
2020-08-18T13:45:43.834012+00:00 app[worker.1]: pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't
 connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")
2020-08-18T13:45:43.963849+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-08-18T13:45:44.028829+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Comment: Where did you host your MySQL server?The hostname should be that ip localhost only work if it is on the same ip as where you are hosting the bot

Comment: Ohh, so my mysql database's ip address must be the same as my bot's ip address? How do I sync them up? I don't know how to check my bot's ip address. The bot is hosted on heroku btw. The database is hosted locally.

Comment: wdym by database hosted locally? Like where you live? If so then change the hostname from localhost to your ip

Comment: So I have to change my hostname to my IP address? Then I can host my bot on heroku?